# What am I? A Stellar Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

Nothing is too hot for me

As is everything else

I'm the darkest and baldest

And the largest and smallest

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the third line, I think the answer must be

> A black hole

Nothing is too hot for me

> Generally, speaking a black hole colliding with a star eventually results in the black hole absorbing the star's matter.

As is everything else

> Black holes are incredibly cold (around $10^{-14}$K) which means other objects in the universe are "too hot" (hotter) than them - including "nothing" (CMB radiation) which may bring a second interpretation on the first line.

I'm the darkest

> Famously, black holes absorb light which gets trapped beyond the event horizon.

and baldest

> This is a reference to the [No-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem)

And the largest

> Probably in reference to [supermassive black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermassive_black_hole)

and smallest

> Possibly a reference to [micro black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole)

As Mithical pointed out in the comments this could also be a reference to

> The singularity at the centre of the black hole.

Comment: Stellar solve. I learned a few things.

Comment: I'd interpret the smallest as referring to rot13(gur fvathynevgl ng gur pragre bs n oynpx ubyr).